# AngularJS, two controller in a page

Tags: angularjs

There are two divs `<!-- Details Div-->` and `<!-- smartTable Div-->`. If either one is loaded alone once or twice in the same page, it works. However If both are loaded simultaneously  `Error: Argument 'objDetailsController' is not a function, got undefined` error is thrown.

This (http://www.angularjshub.com/examples/basics/multiplecontrollers/) tutorial tells us that, there can be multiple controller in the same page.

What's wrong with following design?

```
 <html ng-app="indexApp">
    <head>
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="PRAGMA" CONTENT="NO-CACHE" />
        <meta HTTP-EQUIV="Expires" content="Mon, 01 Jan 1990 12:00:00 GMT" />    
        <meta charset="utf-8" />  
        <script>
            angular.module('AngularJSRemoting', ['Scope.safeApply'], function($provide) {
            $provide.factory('jsr', function($q, $rootScope) {
                //code
                });
            });
        </script>
        <script>                
            angular.module('indexApp', ['AngularJSRemoting','indexApp.controllers','smartTable.table']);
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div> <!-- Details Div-->
            <script>  
                angular.module('indexApp.controllers', []).controller('objDetailsController', function($scope, jsr) {                  
                    //code                                    
                });
            </script>

            <div ng-controller="objDetailsController">
                //Code
            </div>
        </div>
        <div><!-- smartTable Div-->
            <script>
                angular.module('indexApp.controllers', []).controller('smartTableController', function($scope, jsr) {              
                    //code            
                });
            </script>
            <div ng-controller="smartTableController">
                    //Code
            </div>
         </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define your app and add depenedency to your controllers module:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['myApp.controllers']);
```

Create controllers module:

```
var controllers = angular.module('myApp.controllers',[]);
```

Define controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
});

angular.module('myApp.controllers').controller('MyCtrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero2';
});
```

Or in that way:

```
controllers.controller('MyCtrl3', function($scope) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero3';
});
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/aartek/HB7LU/3751/

Answer (score 2):

You are defining the module `'indexApp.controllers'` twice so the second time you define it, it gets overridden.

If you change the smartTable section to something like this it will reuse the existing module

```
<div><!-- smartTable Div-->
    <script>
        angular.module('indexApp.controllers').controller('smartTableController', function($scope, jsr) {              
            //code            
        });
    </script>
    <div ng-controller="smartTableController">
            //Code
    </div>
 </div>
```